# Convert LinkedHashMap to String array

Tags: java

I have a LinkedHashMap of key value pairs of a String key (Name of hotel room) and value Integer of total booking length. My method is supposed to return the top hotel rooms determined by their total booking lengths takes an int as an argument which determines the length of the String array which is returns. I am trying to convert my LinkedHashMap to a String and add it to my String array. I've tried several different ways (These are commented out) and the problem I am getting is when I use for loops to loop through the hashmap and add it to my string of arrays, it doesn't loop properly and when I run the method it just returns the same hotel room

```
Room name = Taff Total time booked = 296
Room name = Taff Total time booked = 296
Room name = Taff Total time booked = 296
```

My method is here:

```
    public String[] getTopRoomsBooked(int n){
      List<Booking> bookings = CSVReader();

      String[] rooms = new String[n];


      // int[] timedBooked = new int[n];

      LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> roomsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
      LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> roomsMapSorted = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();


      for(Booking booking: bookings) {

        int timeBooked = booking.getBookingLength();
        String roomName = booking.getRoomName();
        int totalTime = timeBooked;
        if(roomsMap.get(roomName)!= null) {
          totalTime += roomsMap.get(roomName);
        }
        roomsMap.put(roomName, totalTime);

      }


        roomsMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .forEachOrdered(x -> roomsMapSorted.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));





      //   for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      //   for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : roomsMapSorted.entrySet()) {


      //     rooms[i] = ("Room name = " + entry.getKey() + " Total time booked = " + entry.getValue());


      //   }
      // }


      // int i = 0;
      // for(String key: roomsMapSorted.keySet()) {
      //   rooms[i] = ("Room name = " + roomsMapSorted.get(key) + " Total time booked = " + roomsMapSorted.getValue());
      //   i++;

      // }

      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

      Iterator entries = roomsMapSorted.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
    String key = (String)entry.getKey();
    Integer value = (Integer)entry.getValue();
    rooms[i] = ("Room name = " + entry.getKey() + " Total time booked = " + entry.getValue());

}

}

        return rooms;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to check the CSVReader. You might get some wrong data from there.

But your whole function can be done in 1-2 lines of code by using Java 8 Streams and [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html).

**Example**

```
Map<String, Integer> roomnameAndBookingLengthSum = bookings.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Booking::getRoomName,
            Collectors.summingInt(Booking::getBookingLength)
        )
    );
```

Afterwards you can sort it with your function, which i slightly adjusted. You first sorted your stream to run through it with a sorted for each again.
Once you sorted your stream all following operations will keep that sort.

So i just mapped the sorted stream from `Entry` to `String`. This results in a List of roomNames (ordered by bookingLength ASC)

```
// currently the List is sorted in ASCENDING order like 1,3,4,6,7,8...
List<String> hotelRoomNamesOrderedByBookingLength = roomnameAndBookingLengthSum.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then you simply reverse it to have to room with the top booking length first.

```
// reverse it
Collections.reverse(hotelRoomNamesOrderedByBookingLength);
```

---

**Input**

```java
List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#1", 1));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#2", 3));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#3", 5));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#2", 3));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#1", 8));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#3", 34));
bookings.add(new Booking("Room#1", 8));
```

**Output**

```
Room#2
Room#1
Room#3
```

Comment: Great thank you. I'll use this. But how do I convert it into a String array?

Comment: I added some more explanation and a sample input and output.

Comment: This is great but I wanted a String array which says smoething like "The top rooms are" + roomName + totalBookingLength. SO I need to be able to return rooms[n] which is a string containing the rooms with their total booking lengths